How to light Hanukkah candles acording to Beth Shamai
Nowadays there is more information about the machloketh between Beth Hillel and Beth Shamai. There is even information how to light the candles according to Beth Shamai, but there is no information to about the order the candles are placed in the Chanukiah.

Two thousand years ago they debated how many to light, the debate was settled within a century or two in favor of Beth Hillel, and subsequent halacha was codified accordingly. So nobody would continue to develop more practical details on how to fulfill an opinion that's not followed. (Though theoreticians may, for the fun of it, try to devise what they might have said.)

Is your question about placing candles or about lighting candles?

as the Pri megadim write that חנוכה is an acronym for ח נרות והלכה כבית הלל

@shayachagigah definitely has a better ring to it than חנוכש

Assuming this matters for fulfilling lighting the menorah rather than something practical that developed into a minhag

Two thousand years ago they debated how many to light, the debate was settled within a century or two in favor of Beth Hillel, and subsequent halacha was codified accordingly. So nobody would continue to develop more practical details on how to fulfill an opinion that's not followed. (Though theoreticians may, for the fun of it, try to devise what they might have said.)
